Problem with Sculpting Remesh
I am trying to increase the resolution of the mesh to make it smoother using the 'R' feature. Why does the mesh look blocky every time I apply it? Even when I 'Shade Smooth' I have also tried using the 'Remesh Modifier' and the 'Object Properties' to change this with no success. I am using Blender 3.6.2



It looks like you are using the Subdivision Surface modifier on your model and when you remesh, the remesh is applied first, causing the mesh to look blocky.
To fix this, apply subdivision and then remesh.

I figured it out after much trial and error. Thank you.
